# How to forward github issues to mailing list?

Tags: github, github-api, github-services

I would like to forward (or better said, mirror) github issues (of an Open Source project) to the project's public mailing list.

How can I do it?

Are there any existing solutions using github's API?

(Service hooks in repository settings only forward commits, not issues.)

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over a repository's issues events and store the last ETag header you're sent to then only get recent events. By doing so you can catch new issues, new comments on issues and how the state of those issues. The endpoint is described [here](http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-repository-events) and the data you'll receive is described [here](http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#issuecommentevent).

This of course requires you pinging the API every so often but with an anonymous ratelimit of 60 requests per hour (and an authenticated ratelimit of 5000 per hour) you could at least have emails that are accurate to within a minute of something transpiring (unless you're doing this for multiple repositories, in which case you'd expire your ratelimit much faster).

I don't know of any existing solutions, but one shouldn't be hard to put together.

Comment: If anyone finds or comes up with ready made solution, please post here. Thanks!

Comment: @user975135 there are no ready made solutions. I described to you, however, your best way of creating such a solution though.